# How to add an icon preview to a html list of google store apps?

Tags: html

Basically I have a list of google apps link in a html file, and I want the links to show the preview of the app linked (without searching and then adding the image/icon url manually, for each app). Is it possible?

```html
 

<html><body>
 <ul>
      <li> <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader">Adobe Acrobat</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox">Firefox</a> 
      </li>
 </ul>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Just copy the URL of the play stores image into the img src link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python you can scrape the social media image preview in the meta tags of the page.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader')

html = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
for tags in html.find_all('meta'):
    if tags.get("property") == "og:image":
        print(tags.get("content"))
```

This will return a link to an image which you can either import to your html file, or manually copy it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted it, but honestly I  hoped for a faster/quicker/smarter or just a more elegant way to do the job, without scraping/coding stuff manually